# How To Embed Custom Python Functions and Multiple Wildcards in Snakemake Rules

Tags: python, snakemake

I am new to snakemake and I try to understand it better. I went through the docs, but sometimes I struggle with some of the concepts. Let's assume I have a snakemake rule which is taking an input file, and generates some output.

I prepared a config file that looks like this:

Config.yml:

```
mydir: "/usr/home/data/"
```

My tabular data looks like this:

| sample | file |
| --- | --- |
| sampleA | file1.fastq |
| sampleB | file2.fastq |
| sampleC | file3.fastq |

I read the tabular data into the snakefile:

```
configfile: config.yml

import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_table("samples.tsv").set_index("sample", drop=False)
```

Then I have a rule all at the top of my snakefile which collects the output from my dummy rule:

```
rule all:
   expand("output/{sample}_output.txt", sample=table["file"])

rule dummy:
input: config["mydir"] + "{sample}"
output: "output/{sample}_output.txt"
shell: "sometool {input} {output}"
```

How can I check if the file, i.e. file1.fastq given in my tsv file is in folder A or folder B if i have two sub-directories under the data folder, and then use it depending on its existence as input in the rule? Also how can I name my output after the sample for the respective file? For example, instead of having the output file1.fastq_output.txt, I want the output named to be after the respective sample name sampleA_output.txt, but still use "file1.fastq" as input to run the shell command.

My idea was to check if the file is in folder A or B with a custom python function outside of the snakemake rule with something like this:

```
def get_file(file):  
test = config["mydir"] + file  
if os.path.exists(test) == True:    
  return test
```

and then use this custom function as input for rule dummy

```
rule dummy:   
input: get_file({sample})   
output: "output/{sample}_output.txt"   
shell: "sometool {input} {output}"
```

For renaming the output files based on the respective sample column I thought of using maybe the loc function, since the rows are based on the sample column and can be accessed in this format table.loc["rowname"]["column"]. However, the get_file function does not work properly as input for my dummy rule. I am not sure, why this happens and how I can rename my output based on the sample name, but still use the file column to process my shell command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue I see in your code is that the function-as-input `get_file` should take in input a single parameter being the wildcard object. So something like:

```
def get_file(wc):
    file = table[table.sample == wc.sample]['file'].iloc[0]
    ## Possibly some more logic to return the input file.
    return file
```

Then use the function as:

```
rule dummy:   
    input: get_file,
    output: "output/{sample}_output.txt"   
    shell: "sometool {input} {output}"
```

---

More explanation about `get_file` function: This function should return a string or a list of strings corresponding to the file(s) you want to use as input. E.g. it may return `file1.fastq` or `[path/to/file1.fastq, path/to/file2.fastq]`, whatever.

To get the correct file(s) for a given value of wildcard `sample`, you can query the sample table `table` to get the value of the corresponding `file`. How you implement that is up to you and it's more a python and pandas question than a snakemake one.

What if you want `get_file` to take additional parameters? E.g. explicitly pass `table` and `config` as parameters? Then you can do:

```
def get_file(wc, table, config, stuff):
    file = table[table.sample == wc.sample]['file'].iloc[0]
    ## More work with config, stuff etc...
```

and use it as:

```
rule one:
    input:
        fin=lambda wc: get_file(wc, my_table, my_config, my_stuff),
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help. This expression 
"file = table[table.sample == wc.sample]['file'].iloc[0]"

if I understand it correctly
table.sample would look like this:

sampleA | sample A \n

sampleB | sample B \n 

sampleC | sampleC \n

and inside the square brackets we check if it corresponds to wc.sample
where as sample refers to the wild card object {sample} from the dummy rule and if the expression in the brackets evaluates to true, we access the column entry of that particular row/sample we are looking at?

& why do we use iloc[0] if the samples are row-indexed?

Comment: @user23274796 I edited my answer with some explanation, but I think you got the idea. Regarding *why do we use iloc[0] if the samples are row-indexed* my code may not be 100% correct for your use case, I'm just giving you the idea behind it.